# Есть ли возможность отключить защиту памяти в c++?

Tags: c++, память

У меня есть динамический массив. Я передаю указатель на него в другое приложение. Но когда я хочу там его использовать я получаю AcessViolationException. Как собственно отключить защиту? И возможно ли это вообще

Comment: Так это защита не в C++, а в операционной системе. Хотите отключить - переходите на MS-DOS или Windows 95, в этих ОС защиты памяти не было

Comment: Ну а вообще даже без защиты памяти передача указателя не прокатит, потому что в современных ОС память **виртуальная** и один и тот же указатель в разных процессах может указывать на совершенно разные участки реальной памяти. Лучше изучите и используйте нормальные механизмы межпроцессного взаимодействия (вот по ссылкам ниже например)

Comment: Ну, просто так нельзя. Но можно примерно [так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory). Почитайте [эту статеечку](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory).

Answer (score 0):

Так это защита не в C++, а в операционной системе. Ну а вообще даже без защиты памяти передача указателя не прокатит, потому что в современных ОС память виртуальная и один и тот же указатель в разных процессах может указывать на совершенно разные участки реальной памяти. Лучше изучите и используйте нормальные механизмы межпроцессного взаимодействия (вот по ссылкам ниже например)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory